# Finding the zeroes of this complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Now I thought it wouldn't be too much of an issue, but it is becoming hell to find the zeroes of:

$$z^4 + 10z^2 +1 $$

Now reason I need them is for the poles of a function I am working on. So with the quadratic term I figured ok let me make a quick substitution of $$z^2 = x$$ this is not x of the Reals just a variable. Anyways going through this I obtained:

$$x = (-5 \pm 2\sqrt{6})$$ now with this I figured I was getting close to the solution, then to follow I continued on and brought back in terms of Z:

$$z^2 = (-5 \pm 2\sqrt{6})$$ and with this I was going to attempt to parse out the poles, but the solution in the book has two of the poles as:

$$z_1 = i\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}$$   and the other as: $$z_2 = -i\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}$$

My problem lies in getting all four of the poles in the final two steps. Suggestions?

Comment: HINT: If $z=a$ is a solution of your biquadratic equation then $z=\frac1a$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

By solving $$x^2+10 x+1=0$$ you get $x=-5-2 \sqrt{6}$ and $x=2 \sqrt{6}-5$. Now solve $z^2=x$ which give following equations:
$$z^2-(-5-2 \sqrt{6})=0$$ which satisfies $z=-i \sqrt{5+2 \sqrt{6}}$ and $z=i \sqrt{5+2 \sqrt{6}}$;

Then $$z^2-(2 \sqrt{6}-5)=0$$ which satisfies $z=-i \sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{6}}$ and $z=i \sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{6}}$

Now you have four distinct solutions.

Comment: I got greedy and wanted to solve my plus and minus equations all in one shot and lost track of all the signs.......thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

$$z^2=(−5 \pm 2\sqrt{6})$$

$$z^2=(−1)(5 \mp 2\sqrt{6})$$

$$z=\pm\sqrt{ (−1)(5 \mp 2\sqrt{6})}$$
$$=\pm i\sqrt{5 \mp 2\sqrt{6}}$$

This gives four possible roots:

$$i\sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt{6}}, -i\sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt{6}}$$

$$i\sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt{6}}, -i\sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt{6}}$$